# Removing the first duplicate row and keep the rest?

Tags: r

I want to remove duplicates based on column 'User' but only the first instance where it appears.

DF:

```
User  No
A     1
B     1
A     2
A     3
A     4
C     1
B     2
D     1
```

Result: 
(A1 and B1 removed)

```
User  No  
A     2
A     3
A     4
C     1
B     2
D     1
```

I've been unsuccessful with using the duplicated function.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I've been unsuccessful with using the duplicated function. "? What did you try so far? Please share some code or this question will certainly be closed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this should work

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(User) %>% filter(duplicated(User) | n()==1)
```

The `duplicated()` will tell you if a value has been seen before, but it returns FALSE the first time it sees a value (it's not duplicated yet) and then TRUE every subsequent time it sees that value. In order not to get rid of values that have only one row, we also keep values where the total row count `n()` per group is 1.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(DF)`).  Grouped by the 'User' column, we select all the rows except the first (`tail(.SD, -1)`) where `.SD` is `Subset of Data.table`.  But, this will also remove the row if there is only a single row for a 'User' group. We can avoid that by using an `if/else` condition stating that `if` the number of rows are greater than 1 (`.N>1`), we remove the first row or `else` return the row (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, if(.N>1) tail(.SD,-1) else .SD , by = User]
#   User No
#1:    A  2
#2:    A  3
#3:    A  4
#4:    B  2
#5:    C  1
#6:    D  1
```

Or a similar option as in @MrFlick's dplyr code would be using a logical condition with `duplicated` and `.N` (number of rows).  We create a column 'N' by checking 'User' groups that have a single observation (`.N==1`), in the next step, we subset the rows that have are either TRUE for N or is `duplicated` for the 'User'.  The `duplicated` returns `TRUE` values for `duplicate` rows leaving the first value as `FALSE`.

```
setDT(DF)[DF[, N:=.N==1, by = User][, N|duplicated(User)]][,N:=NULL][]
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be using `ave` to get the logical index ('indx2') by checking if the `length` for each 'User' group is 1 or not.  We can use this along with the `duplicated` as described above to subset the dataset.

```
indx2 <- with(DF, ave(seq_along(User), User, FUN=length)==1)
DF[duplicated(DF$User)|indx2,]
#   User No
#3    A  2
#4    A  3
#5    A  4
#6    C  1
#7    B  2
#8    D  1
```

Comment: I need to remove a duplicate rows based on couple of columns , but with a condition matching to another column. For example,  `duplicated(df$a,df$b) & df$c %in% "B")` , so the column df$a and df$b have duplicates, but they have df$c has a column value A and B. I like to keep those matching to B of these duplicates. Did you answer anything similar to this ?

Comment: You need `duplicated(df[c('a', 'b')]) & df$c %in% 'B'`

Comment: It did not work, added a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67627831/remove-duplicate-row-based-on-conditional-matching-in-another-column

Answer (score 5):

This is not as easy to understand as MrFlick's and akrun's approaches, but is a one-line base R solution

```
#data
DF=data.frame(User=c("A","B","A","A","A","C","B","D"),No=c(1,1,2,3,4,1,2,1))
#solution
subset(DF,duplicated(User)|!duplicated(User,fromLast=TRUE))
```

It gives

```
#  User No
#3    A  2
#4    A  3
#5    A  4
#6    C  1
#7    B  2
#8    D  1
```

Explanation:

```
subset(DF,logicalA|logicalB)
```

- `logicalA` ... selects all duplicated entries and, therefore, omits
  all Users with exactly one entry
- `logicalB` ... selects all Users
  with exactly one entry and selects last entry (see `fromLast=TRUE`)
  of Users with more than one row (the latter are selected by logicalA
  anyway)

I hope I got that right. :)