# Duplicates in data: how to keep a specific row of choice out of several per id

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates

This topic has been discussed many times by many folks. However, I couldn't find a solution for dealing with several versions of data per id – consequently multiple rows per id – while my purpose is to end up with one row per id (aka "tidy data").

Assuming I have an id column (along other columns of data), I'd like to search for duplicates in that column (i.e., more than one row of data per id), and tell R which row to keep for each id, **relative to the other duplicates of that id (i.e., avoid hard-coding which row to keep by rownumber).**

For one id, I could decide that I want to keep only the 2nd row out of 5 rows. For another, I could decide that I want the 3rd out of 6 existing, and so on. The decision is based on me reviewing the data, and is not to be programmed as a criterion.

So far, the *closest* solution I've seen is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739947/6105259), by @MrFlick. However, he applies the same general rule for **all** duplicates found in the column, which doesn't address my need to pick which row to keep independently per id situation. In addition, MrFlick's solution just omits the first row and keeps the rest, which isn't what I want either.

### Dummy Data

```r
id <- c(1 , 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8)
x <- state.area[1:13]
set.seed(123) ; y <- runif(13)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, x, y))


   id      x         y
1   1  51609 0.2875775
2   1 589757 0.7883051
3   2 113909 0.4089769
4   2  53104 0.8830174
5   2 158693 0.9404673
6   2 104247 0.0455565
7   3   5009 0.5281055
8   4   2057 0.8924190
9   5  58560 0.5514350
10  5  58876 0.4566147
11  6   6450 0.9568333
12  7  83557 0.4533342
13  8  56400 0.6775706
```

### What I want

Say I'm ignorant to the data as it potentially has many rows and columns (unlike this toy example).

1. Look for duplicates over the `id` column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
duplicates <-
d %>%
  pull(id) %>%
  duplicated() %>%
  which() %>%
  d$id[.]

[1] 1 2 2 2 5
```

So I learn that values of `id` = 1, 2, 5 have duplicates.

2. I will examine the data for each duplicated id to decide which row I want to keep. For example, let's take a look on id = 5.

```r
d %>%
  filter(id == 5)

  id     x         y
1  5 58560 0.5514350
2  5 58876 0.4566147
```

Based on *my* knowledge, I know that the first instance doesn't make sense (whatever the reason might be), and thus I want to omit the first row of id = 5 and keep the second row, back in my original `d` dataset.

*On the contrary*, when I examine id = 2, I understand that it's the 3rd that I'd like to keep (of id = 2), and omit the 1st, 2nd, and 4th rows – back in the original `d`.

In the same vein, for id = 1, I'd like to keep the *first* row but omit the second.

In sum, I'd like to examine duplicates and specify which row, relative to the other duplicates of that id, to keep in each situation, so the output will look like this:

```r
d %>%
  after selecting which row of each duplicated id:

   id      x         y
1   1  51609 0.2875775
5   2 158693 0.9404673
7   3   5009 0.5281055
8   4   2057 0.8924190
10  5  58876 0.4566147
11  6   6450 0.9568333
12  7  83557 0.4533342
13  8  56400 0.6775706
```

I prefer a pipe/dplyr workflow, but am happy with any working solution.

**Clarification**
I presented here a dataset with several duplicated ids. However, I did that for the sake of demonstrating how in each case I might want to select a different row, based on my own judgement. For me, it will be the most useful to have a solution that works for a dataset with just one id value that is duplicated, and I could scale the solution up if I have more than one duplicated id. In this regard, @Ronak Shah's solution below addresses the situation of many duplicated ids, but I'd be happy for something more narrow for a single case.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want a two step process maybe? Create a routine that separates only the duplicates, You check manually, every duplicated row and then create a function that receives as arguments an ID and the row you'd like to keep.

Comment: Possibly, yes. This is a solution that fits well large-scale duplication issue. Posting the question, I did demonstrate a situation of more than one id value that has duplicates. However, it might be useful to think of the single case where I have just one duplicated id, and I want to tackle only that one, by (for example) selecting the 4th duplicated row out of 6 (of that id). Building a function would be an overkill for just one case.

Comment: For getting user input in the middle of a script, you could use the `readline()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to manually pick the rows to keep - minimizing coding. I would recommend this workflow:

```
d_dedup = d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  mutate(seq_within_id = 1:n(),
         keep_this_one = 0) %>%
  arrange(id, seq_within_id)

write.csv(d_dedup, "deduplication_file.csv")
```

Then, open the deduplication file in your favorite spreadsheet application (or even a text editor), and manually change the `keep_this_one` column to 1 for each row you want to keep. Save it as a new file, maybe `"deduplication_file_complete.csv"`, read it back into R, and check that you haven't missed anything.

```
d_marked = read.csv("deduplication_file_complete.csv")
d_chosen = filter(d_marked, keep_this_one == 1)

# some checks - you might want to do more
all(d_dedup$id %in% d_chosen) # expect TRUE
any(duplicated(d_chosen$id)) # expect FALSE
```

R  is a programming language - it's  not made for manual data entry. If you want to manually adjust data, then a spreadsheet is a better tool. Keeping the workflow scripted like this still leaves an audit trail, which is good.

Comment: You can use `row_number()` instead of `1:n()`

Comment: @Gregor, Thanks. you're right on the point: although this can't be completely automated, I still want the audit trail for keeping my work reproducible. How can I use your solution without leaving R? Assuming that both me and my auditors work with RStudio, we could review the duplicated data still in RStudio, which means that exporting as a csv, modifying, and reading back is unnecessary. In other words, this doesn't need to be interactive. Prompting the viewer of my script to take an action (which row to choose) is unlikely. I just want to leave a trail that shows my decisions along the way.

Comment: The CSV file is your audit trail. You can edit it in RStudio if your prefer that to Excel or whatever. Your other option is to code it manually, e.g., create a data frame with, e.g., `keep = data.frame(id = 5, seq_within_id = 1)`. Then `keep = rbind(keep, data.frame(id = 2, seq_within_id = 3)`... then do a inner join on `keep` and `d_dedup`. But this is much more cumbersome to write, more bug-prone because you'll be doing a bunch of copy/pasting, and less friendly to audit because it's in ugly code rather than a simple CSV. The CSV is a good idea. Anyone can understand and audit the CSV.

Comment: @Emman You can record your reasons for picking rows in comments at the top of the data file with the `keep_this_one` column.  `read.table` and its children have an option to ignore commented lines.  Just start the comment lines with `#`.

Comment: Code is good for recording algorithmic steps. Even random algorithmic steps. But not manual decisions. You want to make potentially a lot of manual decisions, so keeping it in code is asking for trouble.

Comment: @NathanWerth still better to use the spreadsheet and add a "notes" column. Easy to drop a column. Better to have annotations on the line they pertain to than at the top of the file. (Though some general comments at the top might be nice too.)

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, this guidance is helpful. You're giving me perspective about coding practice that I haven't thought of.

Comment: I really want to emphasize the *anyone can audit the CSV* bit. If you have 50 IDs with duplicates, and your manager/advisor/project manager/mom/your future self/etc. wants to audit the choices you made, your choices are a nice CSV with the relevant columns and the choice clearly marked, or 50 lines of code `keep = data.frame(id = 5, seq_within_id = 1); keep = rbind(keep, data.frame(id = 2, seq_within_id = 3); keep = data.frame(id = 3, seq_within_id = 2)`... how much happier do you think the auditor will be with the CSV? I think **very much happier**.

Comment: This is very true in situations of 50 IDs with duplicates. But if we have only a handful, say 1 or 2 duplicated IDs, then the CSV method might become a burden, as it requires one to go out of their way, open Excel (ugh), etc. But I totally see your point and it makes a lot of sense in keeping stuff organized and readable.

Comment: Yes, it definitely depends on the scale. Less than 5 manual choices? Almost certainly you should code it. More than 15, I would say almost certainly use the CSV file. In between? Judgment call...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dataframe (`match_id`) which has all unique `id` and row number to select based on your knowledge. We can do `left_join` on it and use `slice` to select rows. The `id` which have no duplicates would have 1 as `select_row` since they have only one row.

```
match_df <- data.frame(id = 1:8, select_row = c(2, 3, rep(1, 6)))

library(dplyr)
d %>%
  left_join(match_df) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(first(select_row)) %>%
  select(-select_row)

#     id      x     y
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 589757 0.788
#2     2 158693 0.940
#3     3   5009 0.528
#4     4   2057 0.892
#5     5  58560 0.551
#6     6   6450 0.957
#7     7  83557 0.453
#8     8  56400 0.678
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice solution, but I was hoping to minimize coding numbers as much as possible (which you do in creating `match_df`). I don't know if possible, but what I am looking for is to build a pipe that handles it per case, such as -- and I'm making it up here -- `d %>% pull(id) %>%  distinct() %>% "give me the data with only the ith instance of that duplicated id"`. Explaining my thinking better is if we scale down the problem to one id value that has duplicates: we'd probably avoid building a `match_df` table for just one case. What would be a non-hard-coding solution in that case?

Comment: @Emman A non-hard coding solution would only be possible if there is some pattern to select rows. Based on your post, there is no pattern to select rows and you do it based on your "knowledge" which you get after looking at the data. Can you build a general row-selecting logic which can be applied to each duplicate id  ?

Comment: You're right. My problem is that there isn't a good foolproof algorithm to apply, and therefore the decision-making is manual. And I understand that the consequence is using hard-coding to *some* degree, but I was hoping for something simpler in terms of readability. Building a `match_df` is a great solution if I have *a lot* of duplicated ids. But what if I have only one? I know that in my post I asked about more than one duplicated id, but just for the sake of figuring out the simpler solution possible, I'm narrowing down to one duplicated id. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Emman I see. If it is just one id you could do something like `d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(if(n() > 1) 2L else 1L)` where it selects 2nd row for duplicated id. Also another option is you could reduce creation of `match_df` by creating it only for duplicate ids. `match_df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 5), select_row = c(2, 3, 1))` and then do `d %>%
  left_join(match_df) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(if(n() > 1) first(select_row) else 1L) %>%
  select(-select_row)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little late, but you could try this and see:

```
id <- c(1 , 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8)
x <- state.area[1:13]
set.seed(123) ; y <- runif(13)
d <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, x, y))

makeYourChoice <- function(){
  while (length(duplicatedIds > 0)) {

    utils::View(subset(duplicatedId,duplicatedId$id == duplicatedId$id[duplicatedIds[i]]))

    selection = readline("Select The ROW you want to keep: ")


    aux = duplicatedId[selection,]

    duplicatedId <- subset(duplicatedId,duplicatedId$id != duplicatedId$id[duplicatedIds[i]])

    result[j,] <- aux
    j = j + 1;

    duplicatedIds <- which(duplicated(duplicatedId$id))
  }
  return(result)
}


duplicatedId <- d%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  filter(any(n() > 1))

notDuplicated <- dplyr::setdiff(d,duplicatedId)

duplicatedIds <- which(duplicated(d$id))

i = 1;
j = 1;
result <- as.data.frame(unlist(matrix(ncol = ncol(d),nrow = 0)))
colnames(result) <- colnames(d)

myChoices <- makeYourChoice()

finalResult <- rbind(notDuplicated,myChoices)
```

This prompts me for every repeated ID and I get to select any of the rows, and then it just adds my choices to the ones that are not duped.